# After upgrading to 22.04 LTS icons seem broken

Tags: icons, appearance, 22.04

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and when I upgraded, the first thing I noticed was that the icons looked broken, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: broken icons]

I'm in an Xorg session and I tried to change the icons to another theme (I have thousands), but they were all corrupted.

Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have solved the problem! I came across the same problem when I update Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04. I solved this by re-install the gnome desktop

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Also see this similar question here: [Broken icons after updating to Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406403/broken-icons-after-updating-to-ubuntu-22-04)

Answer (score -2):

Somehow the problem got fixed by trying another icon theme again. However, the *Show applications* button looked like this:

[image: Show applications button]

After updating and restarting the system, that got fixed too.