# Broken icons after updating to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, icons, themes, 22.04

**Disclaimer** : I've already tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403982/1163104), but it didn't fix the problem for me.

Hey :)
Some icons seem to be broken after updating to Ubuntu 22.04, as you can see from [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWzUn.png).
It also happens in the screenshot tool when pressing `fn + print screen`.

I've also tried changing icon theme, shell theme, rebooting, updating & `alt + f2` -> `r`, but none of those work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you have solved the problem!
I came across the same problem when I updated Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04. I solved this by re-install the gnome desktop

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! It works !
I still hadn't found a solution, so I really appreciate the answer ! :DD